# Allow 3rd party API access without giving out Parse keys

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to create a method that will allow a 3rd party to send push messages directly from their CRM platform.

I've created Parse Cloud Code to accept the messages as a POST, but in order for them to use it I would need to give them the REST API key, which then will allow them access to the rest of the platform functionality.

Can anyone suggest a solution where I can allow them to send push messages without exposing the keys? I've tried creating an express app within the cloud code but cannot load the https node library to them make a https post to the push function in main.js (using the REST API key).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Parse.Cloud.run() in the express app to run the function in the main.js file.